# plotting multiple geom-vline in a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot two ´geom_vline()´ in a graph.

The code below works fine for one vertical line:

```
x=1:7
y=1:7
df1 = data.frame(x=x,y=y)
vertical.lines <- c(2.5)

ggplot(df1,aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = vertical.lines))
```

However, when I add the second desired vertical line by changing

`vertical.lines <- c(2.5,4)`, I get the error:

```
´Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (7): xintercept´
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: Don't use  `aes()`, just `geom_vline(xintercept = vertical.lines)`.

Comment: Great. Please answer so I can accept it as the answer. Any hint why aes() does not work? Regards.

Comment: This solutuon is also suboptimal because it overrides the legend functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_line() +
    sapply(vertical.lines, function(xint) geom_vline(aes(xintercept = xint)))
```

Comment: This answer can handle subsets of data and therefore facet_wrap. The solution from RLave would place geom_vline in all facets

Answer (score 21):

Just remove `aes()` when you use `+ geom_vline`:

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_vline(xintercept = vertical.lines)
```

It's not working because the second `aes()` conflicts with the first, it has to do with the grammar of `ggplot`.

You should see `+geom_vline` as a layer of annotation to the graph, not like `+geom_points` or `+geom_line` which are for mapping data to the plot. (See [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/) how they are in two different sections).

All the `aesthetics` need to have either length 1 or the same as the data, as the error tells you. But the annotations can have different lengths.

Data:

```
x=1:7
y=1:7
df1 = data.frame(x=x,y=y)
vertical.lines <- c(2.5,4)
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the reference: " Annotations are a special type of layer that _don’t inherit global settings_ from the plot."